# In WPF using MVVM, who is in charge of manage external communications?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I need to create a WPF application using MVVM which will have a bluetooth connection manager and a custom hardware manager.

Where should I put these managers?

In the ViewModel? In the model? Outside of the View, ViewModel & Model?

Thank you

Comment: For example in a class that you inject a view model with. Then you can mock away the implementation in your unit tests.

Comment: "Model" is any other class what is not related to UI. You are asking many questions, but I am not sure what is the problem. Can you explain those scenarios you have listed and your thoughts? I think [software engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mvvm) would be a better place for your question.

Comment: Yes, how I can move the question to software engineering?

Comment: @Sinatr About the problem, I have a Bluetooth server class, and a hardware manager class. I think at first glance they must be instanciated in the ViewModel class. The question is, is this correct? And if not, where they should be instantiated?

Comment: @Sinatr when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a MVVM architecture there is no *"Outside of the View, ViewModel & Model"*. Everything that is UI related is the View. Everything that is the binding source/target for the view is the View Model. Everything else is the Model.
The intention of MVVM is to use binding and a view model to decouple the view from the business logic.

So, a Bluetooth service (or a hardware manager) will be part of the model for sure. *But* if it creates data that must be displayed to the user, you *also* need to introduce a view model that accesses the service model *and* also a service view that renders the corresponding UI controls. So in a 'worst case' the service and manager will spread and cross the application boundaries (MVVM wise).

> I think at first glance they [the model objects] must be instantiated in the ViewModel class. The question is, is this correct?

[image: MVVM dependency graph]

[*image source*](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/278901/MVVM-Pattern-Made-Simple)

Yes, this is correct.When checking the dependency graph you will realize that the model has no dependency to the view model (or knowledge of the view model) and the view. The arrow points from view model to model. This requires the view model to instantiate a reference to the model. The preferred way is to use constructor injection. Then the view creates the view model instances (because the arrow points from view to view model). This is the only way to implement the dependency graph.
In case of dependency injection, all instances are created in a centralized location like an IoC container. An arrow would point from this container to the application (unidirectional).

Comment: Ok guys, I will mark this answer as the best one, despite of I like the "seperation of concern" explained by @kfir, but this answer will limit the solution inside the MVVM pattern and will lead to a single project solution easy to understand for beginers like me. (Even though I have to learn about "constructor injection"). Thank you all.

Comment: Thank you. If you like to learn about dependency injection I can recommend [_MEF_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/) which is a very simple to use .NET framework. You also should know the Dependency Inversion Principle, which elevates the power of dependency injection (and unit testing).

Answer (score 1):

Outside of the project.

---

Make seperation of concern.

make a new Communication project with ICommunication & Communication class.

If you want to take it a step forward - you can implement a communication server project to handle all communication.
You will need also communication client - which is the project that you will reference from your MVVM-WPF project

why?
1. one day you will add other way of communication - it will be easier and cleaner to add another Communication project.
2. one day you will update your communication - it will be easy 
just to chnage DLL.

EDITED:
About the MVVM project:
* the View Model has no logic at all
* make dependency injection from the communication project to the Model and register to incoming information

Comment: When you refer to do a new project, are you talking about having 2 project in the same solution, right? How the main project will use this second one?

Comment: _"About the MVVM project: * the model have no logic at all * the View-model will be injected the communication and register to incoming information"_ That's not true. The model hosts the business logic. As the term 'business logic' implies it contains the logic. The view model only gets display data from the model and delegates user data input. The view model may format this data for display and exposes it via bindings to the view.

Comment: Creating a connection to a data source is model business logic. When the model holds the data, then it must also connect to the data source (e.g. database, bluetooth device). View model is only a binding source, so that the view doesn't need to know the model (the true application logic or business logic).

Comment: Let me correct that. I was thinking about MVC. The model in MVVM holds the business logic.but the rest is correct - the communication should be an outside project. 2 project in one solution - correct. as for the Domain driven design approch - seperate the concern. BionicCode calle is a diffrent service. it can be. either way it is a seperate dll in the main project